# Give Azure web api client access to web api via Azure management portal

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

Some weeks ago I followed this article in MSDN Magazine on how to configure client access to a web api, protected by an Azure AD organizational account and hosted in Azure. It worked perfectly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463788.aspx

But now when I was about to add Another api and client, things have changed in the portal.

The Native Client Application configure Page Azure Management Portal seems to have change in the recent days - there is no longer a "web api" section at the bottom where you can select the web api for the client to access, (see figure 6 in the article) instead there is a "Permissions to other applications" section with a list of applications, but your web api's are not shown there, only Exchange, AD and other "default" Azure apps. I'm pretty confused now how to give a client access to a web api... hope this is the right place to ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes you see are part of the new features released last week.  You can read more about them in a Blog post from the AD Team: "[New OAuth2.0 features make it easy to write Azure AD connected apps for the Web, iOS, Android & Windows!](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/03/12/harnessing-the-power-of-oauth2-0-to-write-azure-ad-connected-apps-for-the-web-ios-android-amp-windows.aspx)"

Interestingly enough, when I create a new application and look at the configure tab a "Windows Azure Service Management API" is an option in the first drop down. You might try looking again today.  For what it is worth I don't see anything other than WAAD and the management API as something I can select.  The selections must be limited for some reason based on account maybe?

Especially in these preview features expect things to change with little to no warning.  Probably the best place to seek out more information is on the [Windows Azure AD Forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/home?forum=windowsazureaditpro).

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'll read the blog post first, then move on to the forums, cheers.

Comment: The blog post didn't help much, but I moved on to the forums, and found this helpful thread which explains it. I got things working using the sample provided by Dan. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/2b03b3c8-47ab-458e-9872-cfd4bc5b678b/granting-native-application-access-to-web-application?forum=WindowsAzureAD